# Cli tool to shift timing of subtitles

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, subtitle

I'm searching for a command line tool that can shift the timing of a subtitle file (*.srt, *.ass).

Comment: Eighteen years ago I had written a perl script to do this on .sub and .srt files. If you are competent in perl you can modify it for .ass files too: https://www.kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?perl_stconv

Comment: Ubuntu Software has GUI applications that make shifting the timing of subtitles much easier to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

Subsync.

Subsync is a command line tool to syncronize srt subtitles.

You can use it to fix subtitles with both constant and variable time shift.

https://github.com/spion/subsync

Ffsubsync

Language-agnostic automatic synchronization of subtitles with video,

so that subtitles are aligned to the correct starting point within the video.

https://github.com/smacke/ffsubsync

Answer (score 4):

Using  `ffmpeg` this command do the job !

[link to the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821502/how-to-delay-subtitles-in-ffmpeg)

```sh
ffmpeg -itsoffset 2 -i subtitles.srt -c copy subtitles_delayed.srt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `srt-stf` (srt subtitles time fixer):

A simple tool written in Python: [netharuM](https://github.com/netharuM) / [**srt-subtitle-time-fix**](https://github.com/netharuM/srt-subtitle-time-fix)

```
srt-stf --file <input_track>.srt --time 00:00:28,500 -o <output>.srt
```

This command will slow the subtitle by 28.5 seconds. And if you want the subtitles to appear sooner simply add the '-n' flag

```
srt-stf --file <input_track>.srt --time 00:00:28,500 -n -o <output>.srt
```